# fetching Dataextension headers using Soap+ssjs

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ssjs

I get no error, my cloud page keeps running

```
   <script  runat= "server">
 Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");
  var username = 'abc';
  var password = 'xyz';
  var payload = '';
  var endpoint = "https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx";
  var custkey = '32-digit';
  var result;

  payload += '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
  payload += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
  payload += '   <soapenv:Header>';
  payload += '      <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis- 
  open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">';
  payload += '         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-24440876" 
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">';
  payload += '            <wsse:Username>' + username + '</wsse:Username>';
  payload += '            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401- 
  wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">' + password + '</wsse:Password>';
  payload += '         </wsse:UsernameToken>';
  payload += '      </wsse:Security>';
  payload += '   </soapenv:Header>';
  payload += '   <soapenv:Body>';
  payload += '        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">';
  payload += '            <RetrieveRequest>';   

  payload += '                <ObjectType>DataExtensionField</ObjectType>';
  payload += '                <Properties>Name</Properties>;
  payload += '                <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">';
  payload += '                <Property>DataExtension.CustomerKey</Property>';
  payload += '                <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>';
  payload += '                <Value>'+custkey+'</Value>';
  payload += '                </Filter>';
  payload += '            </RetrieveRequest>';
  payload += '        </RetrieveRequestMsg>';
  payload += '   </soapenv:Body>';
  payload += '</soapenv:Envelope>';

  try {
  result = HTTP.Post(endpoint,"text/xml",payload,["SOAPAction"],["Retrieve"]);
  } catch(e) {
  result = {StatusCode:500,Response:Stringify(e)};
```

}

The same xml works in soapUi but not in cloudpage
Please let me know where i am missing.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there a reason why you're hand rolling SOAP? If this is a landing page, you can get Data Extension fields more  easily with the Core library's DataExtension.Fields.Retrieve() function https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionFieldsRetrieve.htm or using WSProxy https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_basic_retrieve.htm

Comment: My requirement is to fetch fields in XML formate and then proceed with creation of same DE in other BU

Comment: That seems like an insane amount of effort and processing for no real reason. You can just use WSProxy to retrieve and copy the DE to another BU. Check out my article here on how to do it: https://gortonington.com/wsproxy-to-copy-a-data-extension/

Comment: @Gortonington, Thank you so much for your article, it actually reduced lot of efforts. If possible can you please let me know if there is any additional permissions required for the code to work on Cloud page since i have no access to script activity. Even just retrieval of DE part does not work in cloud page.

Comment: I got this working, had to call the function on load of the page